# When should I repackage my Azure compute role?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

When setting up an Azure Web / Worker Role for the first time I need to 'Package' the project and upload it via the Azure portal. After doing this I can 'Publish' the application from Visual Studio.

Under which circumstances do I need to 'Package' the project again and update it via the Azure portal?
In other words - which changes require the project to be re-packaged?

Note: I need to 'Package' the project in order to upload it via the Azure portal. When I create a Compute Role in Azure, I must upload a package in order to be make the Compute Role operational.

From Azure portal:
*You have nothing deployed to the production environment.*
*UPLOAD A NEW PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you must package your project at the first time. You can publish your azure project for the first time. I'm not sure what prevent from your publishing. Could you explain a bit more.

I fact, the publish is very similar as package. Visual studio just packaged the project and uploaded them to azure on behalf of you.

Comment: I checked and I'm not sure why I need to package before I publish... It was mentioned in [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-cloud-service/) Microsoft article. I seem to be able to publish without a 'Package' operation. What is the reason Microsoft claim a package is needed before publishing?

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer as I stopped creating packages and just publish directly from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Service package contains the role definitions, configuration settings, runtime bits, and other static content bundled with your app. Visual Studio (or PowerShell) creates an encrypted package (actually a zip file that you can look into, when building for emulator) for upload to the named slot you created via the portal.

In the future, there are certain things you can do without rebuilding the package, such as changing instance count and other configuration settings. Also: If you move your static content (such as your CSS, images, etc.) to blob storage, you can then update those directly without ever needing to recreate / redeploy the package (you may need to send some type of signal to your running app, to reload some resources, but that's going to be app-specific). If you have specific exe's or MSI's that get installed as part of your startup scripts, you can move these to blob storage as well, since they can easily be downloaded as your role startup code executes (and this cuts down on package size).

If you change anything defined exclusively in the service definition file (e.g. if you add a role or change a role size), you will have to repackage/redeploy (but you can deploy as an update, which won't take your service down [assuming you have 2 or more instances] or replace your assigned IP address).

Comment: So in essence I should re-package if: 1) I want to add / modify a file that is not part of the build and 2) If I want to add a new settings, correct? If I just want to change the instance number I can 'Publish' without 'Package' + 'Update' first?

Comment: @Gilad Yes, you're correct. If you just want to change the instance count, you don't have to repackage your application. Instance count is set in configuration file (cscfg) existing contents of which can be updated without redeployment. Please note that if you're adding or removing a configuration setting which has an impact on your application code, then you MUST repackage your application and go through the update process.

Comment: What about files that are marked as Content --> Copy Always? I have many static files that Visual Studio copies to the approot directory. If I update the files itself, will 'Publish' put the updated version in the right location or do I need to re-'Package'?

Comment: If it's part of original package, then you'll want to update as part of package. Otherwise, if any VM instance suffers crash or other event where it needs to start from scratch (which happens automatically), it'll reinitialize from whatever's in the deployment package, unless your app knows to look in a specific blob container for updated content after initialization. Then you can update content by pushing to blob instead of rebuilding package. Just curious: how else would up update approot files: RDP? If so, that's impractical: requires update to all instances, and changes aren't persistent.

Comment: I'll try to describe my scenario again: I have a Worker Role with ~40 static files that I update frequently (say, once every two days or so). The file names are constant, only the content changes. All the files are marked as 'Content-->Copy Always' thus are copied to approot. I created a Package and uploaded it via the Azure portal. From time to time I change my code and 'Publish'. If one of my 40 static files has changed, do I need to 'Package' and update via the Azure portal again, or will my 'Publish' overwrite the previous version of these files?

Comment: Short answer, yes. If it's in your package and it changes, then you need to republish.  In your situation I'd look for a different approach, like storing those files on blob storage and serving them from there.